# Can I RDP to MacBook?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

The physical screen is damaged on my MacBook Pro, so I'd like to RDP (or similar) to it from Windows 8.1 Pro, and use my two 24" monitors for a better experience.  While I found Microsoft Remote Desktop in the Mac App Store, that's merely a client for connecting to other machines.  I [need a server component on the MacBook to allow RDP connections](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125792/os-x-rdp-server-application) and translate the desktop experience to the client on the calling machine.

Or, any alternative.  VNC might only provide the exact experience being served by the physical machine.

Comment: @bmike Why did you add the link from my answer to the question? The link is part of answering the question, it seems odd to now be in the question?

Comment: @grgarside Sign to be closed as duplicate, perhaps? It needed other edits, so I put that in as well.

Comment: @bmike It's related, but not a duplicate, since this question asks for any possible solution and asks for alternatives such as VNC. What other edits? No other edits were made to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

macOS does not support RDP out of the box. There does not seem to be a canonical best solution for getting it working, but you can see [OS X RDP server application](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/125792/37797).

VNC is supported by macOS. Go to **System Preferences** → **Sharing** → **Screen Sharing** → **Computer Settings** and enable **VNC viewers may control screen with password**.

Here are windows VNC clients that work well with Mac and a question on setting up the mac sharing:

- [Is there a Windows remote desktop client compatible with Lion's virtual display feature?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24976/is-there-a-windows-remote-desktop-client-compatible-with-lions-virtual-display/80435#80435)
- [Remote Management vs. Screen Sharing?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34443/remote-management-vs-screen-sharing)

Comment: Microsoft remote Desktop in the App store is for macs to access Windows PCs. It doesn't work the other way around though there are hacks to do so. VNC works and there are other remote assistance web applications that do similar things.

Comment: @Steve Your first sentence is a true fact, as already mentioned by OP in their question. I mention VNC in my answer. Am I missing something from your comment?

Answer (score 2):

Teamviewer is a much easier and simpler solution - https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/mac/

Comment: This is a viable alternative for many. There are some security ramifications though to have centralized credentials. Is TeamViewer capable of working peer to peer like RDC/VNC/ARD? That would be a good thing to put in the body of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

NuoRDS is the best RDS server solution I've found for Mac OSX.  I've run it on Mac Minis and a Macbook Air, using Reminna on Linux to control the Macs.  Works flawlessly and is constantly updated as new OS versions are released.  Affordable and I'd definitely recommend you try it.

https://www.nuords.com/downloads/